# Updating a text box in a continuous form with data from text box in form header. MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have an unbounded text box (a date) in the form header. I know how to pass the data from that to a bounded text box in the continuous form. Is there a way to refresh the text box in the continuous form if I change the date in the unbounded text box?

Currently if I change date, only the new records will be affected. For Data Entry, I want to be able to have that field, in all the records being entered to change whenever I update the unbounded text box in the header.

Comment: I have this in the AfterUpdate Event of the unbounded text box ``Me.ContinuousFrmTxtBox.DefaultValue = """" & Me.UnboundedTxtBox & """"``

Comment: Why would you need to change date value of existing records?

Comment: I don't want to change the date on existing records. I just want to change the date for the current data entry set. On the continuous form, if it have 5 recorded entered and I change the date in the header, I only want those 5 records affected.

Comment: Instead of the unbound textbox, I would input date into first record entered and use VBA code in that control's AfterUpdate event to set its DefaultValue property with that entered date. So reference the bound control in your code instead of the unbound. If you want to allow user to change their mind about the date entered for that set of records, then will have to run an UPDATE action.

Comment: Or code physically moves through records displayed on form and changes each or as HansUp said, open recordset (maybe RecordsetClone) of the form's dataset and loop through records.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could certainly copy the value in the text box to the column value on the current row being edited. You could (would) use the before update command of that form.

you simple go:

```
me.MyColumnInDatabase = me.MyTextBoxNameAtTopOfForm
```

You could (would) place the above one line of code in the forms before update command event.